# Unable to get updated value of session variable and Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a web application in asp.net and c#, I am storing text of textbox in Session variable like this:

```
Session["data"]=TextBox1.Text;
```

and on the button click event I am redirecting user to another page.In the second page I am using this variable **Session["data"]** and in page2 there is a back button where I am again Redirecting to page1 where the textbox1 is present.Now on the button click event where I am redirecting to page2 and event is code like this,

```
Session["data"]=TextBox1.Text;
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```

now when I am accessing the value of the Session["data"] it is giving me the previous value.As the content of TextBox1 may get changed,these changes have not been shown.

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Do you have anything in Page_load in page1.aspx that is setting the value of the Session["data"]?

Comment: I am checking that if( Session["data"]!=null)then TextBox1.Text=Session["data"].ToString(); This code sets the value of TextBox1 when user clicks on back button on the page2.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think the  code you are using is worng. You please make a break point and check it again that the values are assigning correctly
Or 
You just set the session to null and then assign the textbox value to it on the click event.

Comment: Assigning the value of Session variable as null worked...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what you want to do here. You say it works (the Session["data"] contains the text of TextBox1?) but you don't see any changes? What changes did you expect? Please give us some more information about this part of the question:

> As the content of TextBox1 may get changed,these changes have not been shown.

Thanks.

**Update:**
Try clearing or remove the session and then refill it.

```
Session.Remove("data");
Session.Clear();
```

Comment: As there is back button in the page2.aspx which redirects to page1.aspx.Now when the user is back to page1.aspx he can modify the content of Textbox1,now the changed text of Textbox1 is saved in session["data"] which is further used.The problem is ,The change in the Session variable is not reflected.

Comment: Updated answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read this I think Respone.Redirect might be causing you to lose your session data

[Don't redirect after setting a Session variable (or do it right)](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx)

> A problem I see over and over again on the ASP.NET forums is the
>   following: In a login page, if the user and password have been
>   validated, the page developer wants to redirect to the default page.
>   To do this, he writes the following code:
>
> `Session["Login"] = true;`
>
> `Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");`
>
> Well, this doesn't work. Can you
>   see why? Yes, it's because of the way Redirect and session variables
>   work. When you create a new session (that is, the first time you write
>   to a Session variable), ASP.NET sets a volatile cookie on the client
>   that contains the session token. On all subsequent requests, and as
>   long as the server session and the client cookie have not expired,
>   ASP.NET can look at this cookie and find the right session. Now, what
>   Redirect does is to send a special header to the client so that it
>   asks the server for a different page than the one it was waiting for.
>   Server-side, after sending this header, Redirect ends the response.
>   This is a very violent thing to do. Response.End actually stops the
>   execution of the page wherever it is using a `ThreadAbortException`.
>   What happens really here is that the session token gets lost in the
>   battle. There are a few things you can do to solve this problem.
>   First, in the case of the forms authentication, we already provide a
>   special redirect method: FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage.
>   This method is great because, well, it works, and also because it will
>   return the user to the page he was asking for in the first place, and
>   not always default. This means that the user can bookmark protected
>   pages on the site, among other things. Another thing you can do is use
>   the overloaded version of Redirect:
>
> `Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx", false);`
>
> This does not abort the
>   thread and thus conserve the session token. Actually, this overload is
>   used internally by `RedirectFromLoginPage`. As a matter of facts, I
>   would advise to always use this overloaded version over the other just
>   to avoid the nasty effects of the exception. The non-overloaded
>   version is actually here to stay syntactically compatible with classic
>   ASP.