# Could not get the updated value of textbox once the page is redirected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a web application in c# and asp.net.I am trying to access the value of textbox and generate a preview in next page with the content of textbox in the page1.When I am generating the preview for first time it works well,but the next time when I change the content of the textbox the value of textbox.Text remains the same.I thought that it is due to the session variable not working fine and posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805265/unable-to-get-updated-value-of-session-variable-and-textbox)
 but when I printed the value of textbox in the same page using

```
Response.Write(TextBox1.Text );
```

it prints the initial value.

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please post some code ..

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your previous post. I would recommend not using the session in favor of leveraging the query string if the information isn't sensative data.

```
Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx?val=" + TextBox1.Text);
```

Then onload of yourpage.aspx you can just read it from

```
Request.QueryString["val"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but the problem is now not with the session variable but the textbox value as I am not getting the updated value.I uploaded it for testing please login in this url http://bugnull.hinduyuvamanch.com/admin.aspx with credentials a,a and then create enter the title and submit now the page is http://bugnull.hinduyuvamanch.com/newpost.aspx,now enter any text and click on preview.Here is the problem lies.